# How to secure dealloc memory for objectiveC Strings in iOS?

Tags: iphone

I am pretty new in iOS development and I have the following question:
In my code I have a UIViewController with a UIText field that will hold a password when user will type in the view. The password is used for authentication in front a server:

```
UItextField* txtPassword;
[myClass loginWithPassword:txtPassword.text];
```

After using it I want to be sure that there are no leftovers of the password in the memory, so an attacker won't be able performing a memory dump of the iPhone and extracting from it the password.

In windows for example I could use the SeucreZeroMemory function for filling a block of memory with zeros.

What is the best way doing it for iOS? Who is responsible to free the `UItextField*` string, and is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is really not needed, you don't need to write zeros over you allocated data to be sure that it is secure. The reason is that no one but you can access the memory and iOS uses address space randomization so even if it would be possible to get your memory, its hard to guess where your data is (and if one don't know where the data is, it is hard to guess what exactly the data is, luckily the RAM has no filesystem that helps in such a case).
The second thing is, if you use `[foo release]` and you textfield gets deallocated in this process, the OS reclaims the memory. Now the OS will always fill new memory pages with zeroes before giving it to the asking process, so you don't have to fear that there is an malicious app that just allocates memory in the hope it finds the password this way.

Comment: @JustSid "[i]OS will always fill new memory pages with zeroes before giving it to the asking process" -- [citation needed]

Comment: @PeterJenkins Sorry, this isn't skeptics.SE mate. I have the info from one of the WWDC 2010 videos where they go a little bit into depth about the allocator.

Comment: @JustSid If the allocator zero's the bytes, that wouldn't affect an attacker's use of raw malloc, right? Both iOS and OS X use lazy allocation, so malloc doesn't actually give you real memory until you go to use it. I'm also pretty sure I've created objective-c pointers on the stack and had them pointing to garbage data, although that was in the simulator and not on the device. Further, does ARC change anything? If malloc in iOS really zeroed out memory before returning the pointer, I wouldn't expect to have such a hard time finding documentation saying so.

Comment: @PeterJenkins I never said that malloc() returns zeroed memory, I said that a newly allocated physical page gets zeroed. And yes, malloc() does use lazy allocation. However, don't confuse this with what calloc() does, you never know if your memory is backed by a fresh page.

Comment: @PeterJenkins Also, if you really searched for this, you would have stumbled over this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.pdf) which includes the section `Allocating Large Memory Blocks` which clearly notes that ne physical pages are zeroed.

Comment: @JustSid Thanks for the responses (and sorry btw if I came off as rude). I did some testing using GCC on a jailbroken iPad (5.1.1). Wrote a small c program that malloc's memory and prints the contents. I can confirm that I got back all zeros with my initial allocation (repeated trials). If I write to that memory and then malloc another block of the same size, I get back the same memory, with contents intact. That confirms your statements that malloc doesn't always return zero'd memory, but allocating memory to try to find random data from another process doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score -1):

ok,
Release your object which store the password in your class by going into the dealloc methods.
Or release when ever the use that object is finished.by writing this [object release];
I hope it will help you .

Comment: That won't wipe the password from memory immediately though, will it.

Comment: right @trojanfoe. But release is the only thing an iphone developer can do. is it?

Comment: I think the OP was looking for something that cleared the memory before releasing it; something like `memset()` and then release.

Comment: One could alloc the object with a specific NSZone and then overwrite the zone with zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use [object release] for a UItextField object? I wasn't the one who initialized it. (it was probable was initialized when the view was init from a nib file).